# Completely remove a Doctrine entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I deleted a .php file which contained a Doctrine mapped class, let's call him Entity.php.
Now, I want that same model to be removed from my mapping in doctrine. But all my attempts to generate a migration using the migration bundle or recreating a schema fail somehow.
I can't simply update my ORM, and expect the table to be dropped from the database. Also clearing the cache and dropping the database/recreating the database has no influence. It keeps complaining the file is gone, which is ... on purpose!

So, how do I remove an entity from my Doctrine ORM and get rid of the table in the database?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of configuration are you using? YAML, XML or Annotations?

Comment: do you have a doctrine folder in your resources/config ? if yes then you have to delete the file with the name of your entity

Comment: No I don't.. It's really weird. Nothing even references the file. It's somehow stuck in the Symfony CLI. Even clearing cache for every possible combination of debug and production/test envs doesn't do the trick

Comment: And `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` is not working?

Comment: Nope, it tells me the file I deleted does not exist.

Comment: `opcache` or `apc` enabled for cli ?

Comment: Not that I know off. I haven't enabled the myself. Are those default?